# Calling method on script on another gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to call the void of a script which is attached to another GameObject like this:

```
GameObject nHit = _LaserScript.hit.collider.gameObject;

DamageScript nDamage = nHitGameObject.GetComponent<DamageScript>();
nDamage.TakeHit(hit.point, (int)Weapon));
```

The compiler error that I'm getting is "Member 'DamageScript.TakeHit(Vector3, int)' can not be accessed using an instance reference. Instead, qualify it with a type name'.

I'm not sure what the compiler wants from me.

I have also tried this, but it resulted in the same error:

```
nHitGameObject.GetComponent<DamageScript>().TakeHit(hit.point, (int)Weapon));
```

Thank you!

Comment: You most likely have declared the `TakeHit` function `static`. Remove the `static` keyword.

Comment: That solved it. Thanks.

Comment: By the way "the void of a script" is not the correct way to refer to a method. `void` is just the return type (in this case, there isn't any return type), so that's like saying, "I'm trying to call the int of a script" which makes no sense. The correct name is "method" or "function" and the return type isn't relevant (though sometimes helpful). In either case, you should also have included the code for the method you were trying to call.

Comment: @Draco18s Thank you, I never noticed that, but it makes total sense, thank you!!